# React.js - how to set state on form submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Newbie React question - I've got myself thoroughly confused trying to follow the docs.

I want a simple text input that on button click, displays the input value below the form. Pretty simple, right?

This is my component so far:

```
export default class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <input type="text"  value='' />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <p>{ this.state.value }</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't work at all - the form doesn't display anything when the user types.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changes:

**1.** You need to remove the `value=''` from input element otherwise it will not allow you to type any thing, you are not using any onChange function also.

Ways of using elements:

**[Controlled Component:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)** Define a onChange function and value property and update that value inside that change function.

**[Uncontrolled Component:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)** Don't define the value property, use `ref` to get the value of element.

**2.** Use [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) with input element to get it's value in `onSubmit` function.

Check this:

```js
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: this.element.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <input type="text" ref={el => this.element = el} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <p>{ this.state.value }</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TextInput/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: I'd stay away of using refs, better to use controlled inputs :)

Comment: @Crysfel personal preference, why i used `ref` here is, OP want to show the value only after the submit button clicked, if we use `controlled component` then it will reflect the input value during the typing, to achieve that specific behaviour :)

Comment: @Crysfel run your code it will update the dom as user will start typing :)

Comment: @Richard glad, it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a controlled input, you would save the value as the user types into the textfield, then on submit you can get the data form the state.

```
export default class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = (event) => this.setState({ value: event.target.value });

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    consoole.log(this.state.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <p>{ this.state.value }</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the conventional way to get the user's input, using a controlled component.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in

```
<input type="text"  value='' />
```

take out the value

```
<input type="text" />
```

"value" will set the content to an empty string on every render

Answer (score 0):

When using your handle submit function, the event.target is the form element, which has no value, so nothing is set. The "react way" to handle this is to use something called "controlled inputs". Take a look at how I would implement them with your code:

```
export default class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      value: ''
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: this.state.input });
  }

  updateInput(event) {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <input type="text"  value={this.state.input} onChange={this.updateInput} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <p>{ this.state.value }</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice especially the new value of input and the change handler I've attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me at all!! Until I threw in the setState into the onChange itself in the form Return see below - onChange={ e => this.setState({ name : e.target.value })}:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import '../App.css';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {cakes: [], name: '', review: '', rating: ''}

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
}//compdidmount

handleChange = (event) => this.setState({name: event.target.value, review: event.target.value,rating: event.target.value});

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.name + this.state.review + this.state.rating);

  }

  render() {

    const { state } = this;

 const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
 // Correct! Key should be specified inside the array.
 <li key={number.toString()}
           value={number}> {number} </li>

);
    return (
      <div className="Dashboard">
        <header className="Dashboard-header">
                    Dashboard
          <h6 className="Dashboard-title">Items pulled from firebase</h6>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
         Items
        </p>
        {listItems}

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={state.name} onChange={ e => this.setState({ name : e.target.value }) } />
        </label>
        <label>
          Review:
          <input type="text" value={state.review} onChange={ e => this.setState({ review : e.target.value }) } />
        </label>
        <label>
          Rating:
          <input type="text" value={state.rating} onChange={ e => this.setState({ rating : e.target.value }) } />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the examples seem to be more complicated than they need to be. This example is from the Codevolution's React tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9UEDRbLhJE

```
class TextInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            mytext: "",
            value: ""
        }
    }

    changeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    submitHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            value: this.state.mytext
        })
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
            <label>
                <input
                name="mytext"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.mytext}
                onChange={this.changeHandler} />
            </label>
            <button
                onSubmit={this.submitHandler}
                type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            <p>{ this.state.value }</p>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Changes on the `form` update the `state` fields so when you hit submit, everything is ready. Each `input` field is `name`d it's easy to map them back on to their `state`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

const formField1 = useRef();
const formField2 = useRef();

// Form Submit Handler
const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputField1 = formField1.current.value;
    const inputField2 = formField2.current.value;
    console.log(inputField1, inputField2);
    // do something with values
    }
  };

// Your Form
<form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
    <label>
      <input
        ref={formField1}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Form field 1 placeholder"
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        ref={formField2}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Form field 2 placeholder"
      />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The above is an example using the useRef hook! I realize you are using a class based Component, but a functional component makes it so much easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).